# Javascript diff between objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show a table in my html that shows a CRUD log. My php script is selecting and storing the object before and after the UPDATE and saving the json object to the table. This is what my html table looks like:

[image]

Im trying to get it to show whats changed by comparing the 2 objects and finding the objects that don't match then showing in the table name:old value and name:new value in a readable view.. This is my function (that is returning no difference)

```
$scope.parsehistory = function(old, neww) {
       try {

    var o1 = JSON.parse(old),
        o2 = JSON.parse(neww);



    var old_value = _.omit(o1, function(v, k) {
        return o2[k] === v;
    });

    const new_value = Object.keys(old_value).reduce((accumulator, key) => {
        accumulator[key] = o2[key];
        return accumulator;
    }, {});

    var length = Object.keys(old_value).length;
    var keys = Object.keys(old_value);

    console.log("length:", length);
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var name = keys[i];

        var oldvaluee = old_value[name];
        var newvaluee = new_value[name];
        var valuechanged = name;
        console.log("newval", newvaluee);
        console.log("oldval", oldvaluee);
        console.log("valuechanged", valuechanged);
        //studyCrudlog=function(uid,original_value,new_value,description,componant_name,study_id)
        //AppStorage.studyCrudlog($scope.newuser.users_id,oldvaluee,newvaluee,(valuechanged + " value changed."),"Users",AppStorage.getStudy().id);
    }
} catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
  }
}
```

Below is the result of the

> console.log("newval", newvaluee);
>               console.log("oldval", oldvaluee);
>               console.log("valuechanged", valuechanged);

[image]

In this case, the difference would be numberid and sitename

Any assistance would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please share an example of a sample input and expected output.

Comment: Hi i have edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is almost close, you just need to use `omitBy`.

[**_.omit**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit)
 accepts `string[]` which basically removes any keys specified in the array.

[**_.omitBy**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omitBy)
 accepts a callback where the properties are filtered accordingly with more control.

```js
const o1 = {sitename: "newValue", numberid: "newValue", id: "28"};

const o2 = {sitename: "newValue33", numberid: "newValue33", id: "28"};

const oldValue = _.omitBy(o1, (v, k) => o2[k] === v)

console.log(oldValue);

const newValue = Object.keys(oldValue).reduce((a, b) => { a[b] = o2[b]; return a;}, {})

console.log(newValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's still returning the full object mate

Comment: May be there is something wrong, isn't the example I posted is what you expect to happen?

Comment: Yeah your example works mate but when i switch to   const o1 = JSON.parse(old);const o2 = JSON.parse(neww);  it doesnt, the only difference is my parsed json object is enclosed in [{}] rather than just [].. could that be why?

Comment: in the inspector when i log your example is {blabla} and mine is [{blabla}]

Comment: So, you are looking for an array of objects? Does your array contain more than one object or it is always one?

Comment: i was going to use an ng-init on each ng-repeated row so it can be either.. i just thought one might be easier. (there will never be an array in the object they are allways strings)

Comment: Its only returning as an array because it comes from php via ajax

Comment: I am not sure I am getting what you said, could you please post the `old` and `new` values that you pass on to your function?

Comment: old is [{"id":"28","numberid":"newvalue","site_name":"newvalue","site_location":"newvalue","contact_id":"10","country":"United Kingdom","timezone_id":"1","investigator_name":"gaz,yoo,hi-there","investigator_email":"gaz@gaz.com","office_phone":"newvalue","mobile":"gaz","assigned":"test,neww,kjnkjnkn"}]

Comment: new is newwwww [{"id":"28","numberid":"newvalue33","site_name":"newvalue33","site_location":"newvalue","contact_id":"10","country":"United Kingdom","timezone_id":"1","investigator_name":"gaz,yoo,hi-there","investigator_email":"gaz@gaz.com","office_phone":"newvalue","mobile":"gaz","assigned":"test,neww,kjnkjnkn"}]

Comment: it was becaus eit was array not object.. ive fixed... thank you

Comment: Yeah, it's an array with just one object. So almost similar. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Please see this piece of code.It would give the list of changed values, assuming that the object would have the same structure.

```
    /*Checks if objects are same*/
function isObjectsSame(a, b) {
  var objStringA = JSON.stringify(a),
    objStringB = JSON.stringify(b);

  return (objStringA == objStringB);
}

function objDiff(a, b) {
  var isSame = isObjectsSame(a, b);
  var changeTracker = [];
  if (isSame) {
    console.log('Objects are equal.No values changed');
  } else {
    var keys = Object.keys(a),
      key;
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      key = keys[i];
      if (a[key] != b[key]) {
        changeTracker.push({ //Captures the difference.
          key: key,
          value: [a[key], b[key]]
        })
      }
    }

    console.log(changeTracker); // Prints the difference
  }
}
```

Please pass  your objects to the function `objDiff(obj1,obj2);`

Comment: For some reason im getting false

Comment: My Bad.Edited the answer.Can you pass the objects to the function objDiff